# How to return corresponding string values of largest numerical values in column up to certain percentage in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, vlookup, percentage, conditional-formatting

I need to identify names of employees who have generated the top 80% of revenue. Column A is employee name, Columns B-E are revenue totals for each employee by Quarter. How can I identify these employees either by highlighting or VLOOKUP?

I started by trying to sum the largest values in the revenue a column up to a certain percentage or number.? I was trying to somehow use SUM() and SUMIF() with LARGE(), but I haven't been able to figure it out. Ideally, I would like to be able to do this without having to sort the column in descending order since this formula will be applied to multiple columns.

So ultimately I need a formula that returns the employee names, not just the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of the top values use:

```
=IF(AND(SUM($D$1:$D1)+ AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$16,ROW(1:1))<SUM($B$2:$B$16)*$G$1,OR(D1<>"",ROW(1:1)=1)),AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$16,ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then to get the name assciated with that value:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$16)/($B$2:$B$16=D2),COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: @user4100980 I made a few changes, as the original was doing the proper maths.

Comment: This was working, but it doesn't include all of the largest values in the top 80%. There are 17 values/names that should be included, but the rest of the column is blank after the 6th row. It also adds names to the bottom of the returned Names column that line up with blank corresponding Value cells, which should not be included in the sum anyway as they are actually in the bottom 20%. I'm not aware of any errors in the columns, although there are blank cells in the Value columns if that person didn't generate any revenue that quarter. I tried to include an image, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @user4100980 so you have 85 names?  And you are using the new formulas I edited.  Because the first ones were wrong.

Comment: @user4100980 you would need to post the image on imugr or dropbox and post a link.  I think you need 50 rep points to post a photo.

Comment: @user4100980 I just realized that I had your requirements a little backwards.  I read it that you wanted the top 20% I adjusted the first formula.  See edit.  Sorry.

Comment: Column A: Name (31 names); Column B: Revenue (27 values); Column C: Value (6 values); Column D: Name (10 names) - the 6 values in column C don't add up to 80% of the total though, and I can't figure out why the extra 4 names are added to the bottom of column D that don't correspond to any value in column C

Comment: Sorry, just saw your newest comment about the new formula - I changed that, but now Column C includes 4 extra values that put the sum of that column well OVER 80% of the total, and the extra 4 names in Column D that have no corresponding value in column C are still included.

Comment: I just stepped out for the evening. I will look into it more this weekend. I am understanding better what you want. Maybe someone else will come along and give a better answer before I come back.

Comment: @user4100980 see edits, it now stops so that the percentage does not go over the threshold.

Comment: For some reason, the formula seems to only be populating every 6th value in the column, regardless of the fact that some of these numbers should not be included in the top 80%. I have my data in a pivot table - would this have any effect on the formula? When I copy and paste the data into A1 of a new sheet, the formula works perfectly.

Comment: And is there a way to return blank cells instead of #NUM! if the referenced cells have no value in them?